# React Semantic UI Table Cell Does not Respond to onClick

Tags: reactjs, onclick, semantic-ui

I have a [Semantic UI Table](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/) in my functional React component. I want to handle `onClick` events for individual cells. I expect the following to log to console every time I click inside the cell.

```
import React from "react"
import {Table} from "semantic-ui-react"

const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Table celled>
            <Table.Body>
                <Table.Row key="1">
                    <Table.Cell onClick={console.log("Clicked")}>Cell</Table.Cell>
                </Table.Row>
            </Table.Body>
        </Table>
    )   
}
```

Instead I see a single "Clicked" log when the component is first rendered. After that, nothing else causes the cell to write to the console.

This sounds like the issue described in [semantic ui react select table cells not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068492/semantic-ui-react-select-table-cells-not-working). There the problem was improper binding to the class component, but I am using a functional component so that is not the problem for me.

How do I rewrite this minimal table so that `onClick` events are handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your onClick like this:

```
onClick={() => console.log("Clicked")}
```

With  `onClick={console.log("Clicked")}`  onClick handler will be executed every time the component renders.